# Ethernet PHY is busy for getting eye diagram

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, kernel-module

I'm working with Marvell (Ethernet) PHY as a part of an embedded Linux system (as a part of the kernel module), and I want to get eye diagram statistics, but I get the PHY is busy all the time while the Ethernet cable is connected (and it performs Ethernet protocol). Marvell PHY has its own feature to measure eye diagram.

I have tried to disconnect the Ethernet cable physically and then it is performing eye diagram measuring successfully, but the data then doesn't have much sense, because you want to measure the eye diagram on real physical lines. But just when I connect the Ethernet cable, the link became active, and then when I try to measure eye diagram statistics, I got PHY is busy and not able to do that job (eye diagram measuring). I checked traffic over Ethernet, and there is really low-density traffic, like one message (288 bytes) every 15 seconds, and from the Linux side, I minimized communication with PHY.

How I can force it to measure eye diagram during the Ethernet cable is physically connected to PHY? Had somebody had the same issue? How did you fix it? Is there some kind of priority or something that's blocking Marvell PHY to measure that data during the link is connected physically?

Comment: Any chance you're thinking about it wrong and the purpose of the test is for probing the eye diagram between the MAC and PHY? Do eye diagrams even apply to the PAM5 signaling gigabit Ethernet uses on the wire?

Comment: Thank you @Spiff for the comment very much. It reminded me to check that thing deeper, but it's not up to that as I think still. Well, I guess I will contact Marvell company for more info, so I will share information about this. In the meantime, if anybody else has some idea, it is very welcome! :)